# Cursor:pointer is not working on a div with image

Tags: html, css

I want so change the cursor to a pointer when hovering on a div, however my code doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

HTML:

```
  <a href="try.html"><div id="kyoto" style="height:160px; width:1000px;" class="box">
    <li><img id="kyoto_pic" src="kyoto_pic.jpg" alt="Kyoto" height="158" width="340">
    <p id="kyoto_description"><span class="title"><strong>Kyoto </strong></span> <span class="description"> - The fascinating city of history and culture.&nbsp&nbsp</span><a class="top_destinations_link" href="try.html">Read >></p>
    </li>
  </div></a>
```

CSS:

```
  #kyoto{
        margin-top: 10px;
       cursor: pointer;
        }
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine look here:

```css
#kyoto{
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="try.html">
  <div id="kyoto" style="height:160px; width:1000px;" class="box">
    <li>
      <img id="kyoto_pic" src="kyoto_pic.jpg" alt="Kyoto" height="158" width="340">
      <p id="kyoto_description"><span class="title"><strong>Kyoto </strong></span> <span class="description"> - The fascinating city of history and culture.&nbsp&nbsp</span><a class="top_destinations_link" href="try.html">Read >></p>
    </li>
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working for me. I mean, when I'm hovering the image, the cursor has the pointer aspect. Unless I didn't understand your problem... (watch my following Codepen, and tell me)

**BUT...**

I created a Codepen for your problem, [just here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rqrBoP). As you can see, I added some borders and backgrounds then you can see your code is not completly clean because every element overflows on its parent.

Moreover, your code is not really valid. If you want to use an image with a text legend, I suggest you to use the `<figure>` tag, it is more appropriate. To get some help, follow [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure).